# How to use singleton with realm object?

Tags: singleton, realm

I have an User model:

```
class User: Object, Mappable {
    dynamic var account: String?
    dynamic var balabala

    static var current: User  {
        return realm.objects(User.self)  ?? User()
    }
}
```

But it throws an error: `Instance member 'realm' cannot be used on type 'User'`
How to use singleton with realm object?
Any help is appreciated

Comment: I thought managed objects in swift already receive a `realm` property, so that's odd.

Comment: Yep, its exactly like this error said, you cannot create realm instance of realm class inside, better option would be 1. create another class, some kind of account manager and there put your singleton 2. leave singleton alone, you can always base on your realm object, i.e: create primary id for every user and then you can delete current user, or check if exists

Answer (score 0):

Your `User` class doesn't define an instance variable called `realm`, so in your `current` property the Swift compiler doesn't know what `realm` refers to.

If you just want to use the default Realm, you need to initialize a new instance of it:

```
try! Realm().objects(User.self)
```

Otherwise, as Kam referred to in the comments, set up a separate class for managing your singleton Realm and get the Realm from that class instead.

Comment: I have defined realm as a global variable : `let realm = try! Realm()`

Comment: Okay, that's good to know; this is one of Swift's many awful error messages.  Here is the real problem: `realm.objects(User.self)` returns a `Results<User>`. You need to change your code to `realm.objects(User.self).first ?? User()`, otherwise the types won't match up and Swift's type checker will become confused.

Comment: Please send a reproduction case to help@realm.io if you want us to take a further look.